# issues with FlipperView

Tags: android, xml, layout, viewflipper

Quick question, when I try to assign a variable to the id of a flipperview in an xml file, I get an issue that doesn't allow me to find the id of the flipper.

mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.your_flipper); contains an error that the id of the flipper view is not there.

The flipper view won't take the id assigned in the xml file and place it in the R.java class for some reason.

Any ideas why or is the id of a flipper not supposed to be accessible in the class?

Comment: How is your XML looking like? The ViewFlipper is not different from any widgets in terms of visibility from within the application. Pls. also add the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your layout XML file does not have the `ViewFlipper` under that ID, or you need to clean your project. To do the latter, use `ant clean` from the command line or Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu.